# Changing string in 'list format' to a string

Tags: python

I have the following list;

```
lst = ["['atama', 'karada', 'kami', 'kao', 'hitai', 'me', 'mayu', 'mabuta', 'matsuge', 'hana']", 
       "['head', 'body', 'hair', 'face', 'forehead', 'eye', 'eyebrow', 'eyelid', 'eyelash', 'nose']"]
```

I need to get the contents of each item set as a list, so that I can print the items individually. Eg.

```
for item in lst:
    for word in list(item):
        print word

>>

atama
karada
kami
kao
etc.
```

Any ideas how I could format the str(item)|s to lists once again?

Comment: Is the goal to just take lst and create a list containing all of the items within the lists in lst?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the goal is to create lists (one, two) containing the contents of the strings contained in the list.. Wow I'm bad with words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of several methods:

1) Manually extract each list item:

```
lst = [[item.strip()[1:-1] for item in element[3:-3].split(',')] for element in lst]
```

2) Use `eval`:

```
lst[:] = eval(lst[0]), eval(lst[1])
```

3) Use `json`:

```
import json
lst = [json.loads(i) for i in lst]
```

Methods 1 or 3 are preferred. `eval` is unsafe, as any string passed to `eval` will be (surprise, surprise) evaluated. Only use `eval` if you have complete control over what is being passed to it.

4) Another solution that occured to me, use regular expressions:

```
import re
lst = [re.findall("['\"](\w+)['\"]", item) for item in lst]
```

Comment: The first option in this worked well :) The only thing is, I get string items as follows : "'karada" : Is there a way to prevent "'" from ocuring at the start of each subsequent item? Thank you :)

Comment: Spot on! Thanks heaps for your help, once again! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import ast
>>> L = ["['atama', 'karada', 'kami', 'kao', 'hitai', 'me', 'mayu', 'mabuta', 'matsuge', 'hana']", 
       "['head', 'body', 'hair', 'face', 'forehead', 'eye', 'eyebrow', 'eyelid', 'eyelash', 'nose']"]
>>> for item in L:
        for word in ast.literal_eval(item):
            print word


atama
karada
kami
kao
hitai
me
mayu
mabuta
matsuge
hana
head
body
hair
face
forehead
eye
eyebrow
eyelid
eyelash
nose
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(one, two) = (list(lst[0]), list(lst[1]))
```